# discord.py bot duplicating outputs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My Discord Bot seems to be doing everything twice. At first, I thought this was a cog issue but upon adding a testing function to the main .py file, even doing #test responds twice. Furthermore, when an unrecognised command is run, I will get an error message twice. How do I amend this?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import os #For Loading/Unloading Cogs

token="[redacted]"

help_command = commands.DefaultHelpCommand(no_category = "Placeholder")
client=commands.Bot(command_prefix="#", help_command=help_command) #The prefix for the Bot is "#", Changes the default group title for cogless commands.

for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"): #Checks that the file in the cogs folder ends with ".py".
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}") #Loads cogs whilst cutting of the ".py" file extenstion.   
        print(f"{filename} has been loaded")

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("test done")

client.run(token)
```

Comment: Run the task manager (`Ctrl + Shift + Esc`) and search for hidden python processes and kill them, another option is to restart the pc itself

Answer (score 0):

There is no mistake in your code, make sure you don't have multiple [instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461907/what-is-meaning-of-instance-in-programming)
or just restart your computer.